# How to put a text watermark on a video using ffmpeg command in android

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg, watermark

I am trying to put watermark on the video file which i am compressing using ffmpeg library.

What exactly is the command that i need to put to put a text watermark on the video file??

I have tried using this command :

```
String commandStr = "ffmpeg -i " + inputpath
                    +" drawtext=fontfile=/usr/share/fonts/truetype/freefont/FreeSerif.ttf: text='Test Text' -strict experimental -s " + str_resolution
                    + " -ac 2 -ar 44100 -b "+str_bitrate+" "
                    + outvidpath;
```

After using this command the video does not get generated. What could possibly could go wrong in this command??

Please help! Thanks in advance!

Comment: This answer might help.

http://superuser.com/questions/701152/ffmpeg-drawtext-and-watermark-only-creates-watermark-but-no-text

Comment: You should also include the complete `ffmpeg` output.

Answer (score 0):

My first preferences for watermarking with text and image use "Mencoder". it is better and simple that FFmpeg

I have looked in your command. it seems your video file name have black space, so use double quotes to enclose file name. or video file is not in the folder.